# Elasticsearch updates in transaction

Tags: java, oracle, elasticsearch, transactions

I have following situation:

The blue circle represents a start/end of a transaction. The green dots are es updates.

[image: transactions]

If the transaction fails due to for example 2 users editing the same row (rowVersion error), I want to rollback the es index updates in the transaction.

I know there is a version for every update but how do I revert 1, 3, 5 and 6?

Is there a better solution? I was thinking in the line of keeping changes and do an update after the commit. But what if my index update fails?

Comment: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Distributed-transaction-support-td951313.html

Comment: How do you sync your data with ES? what is ES used for in your application? to prevent dirty reads, I would only update ES after commiting the main transaction

Comment: Java. Searching in huge amount of data. And that is more or less what I ment with the last 2 lines of my question :-) Fingers crossed the index updates work :-)